# deploying react web app into AWS amplify.(Mac)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github, dependencies

My command line is giving me this error:
- npm WARN @aws-amplify/api@2.1.3 requires a peer of @aws-amplify/pubsub@^1.2.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

I did some digging and followed several solutions but I still can't move forward and once I run " amplify init" - the same error is popping back up.

Comment: Can you describe the solutions that you've already tried?